# extract from a JSON array (JMeter)

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, jsonpath

what is the best approach to capture from the following array?

- i only need to capture the value of ANY 'beginDate', e.g: 2017-05-01T08:30:00 could be a valid one in below example
- i need to make sure the **'beschikbaar' = TRUE** for the date that i'm capturing

i tried using json path extractor with similar lines: **$..[?(@.beschikbaar == 'true')].beginDate** but i'm facing syntax errors that i cant fix due to my limited regex/json path knowledge

the example array is;

```
{

"data":
[
    [
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T08:00:00",
            "eindDate":null,
            "beschikbaar":false
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T08:15:00",
            "eindDate":null,
            "beschikbaar":false
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T08:30:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T10:30:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T08:45:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T10:45:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T09:00:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T11:00:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T09:15:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T11:15:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T09:30:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T11:30:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T09:45:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T11:45:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
        {
            "beginDate":"2017-05-01T10:00:00",
            "eindDate":"2017-05-01T12:00:00+02:00",
            "beschikbaar":true
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for JSON data, JMeter provides [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) designed to work with JSON data via [JSON Path Language](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) so you should be able to get your "beginDate" with the query like:

```
$..[?(@.beschikbaar == true)].beginDate
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Conditional JSON]

Check out [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation and few more examples.

Comment: oh crap... i used 'true' instead of just plain true and wondered why it didnt work for an hour :) thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
(?s)\{.*?\"beginDate\":\"([^{]*?)\"[^{]+\"beschikbaar\":true.*?\}
```

`(?s)` is single-line modifier which makes `.` match the line break

You can test it at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

And set `Template` to `$1$` means using the first group